# Reading file and comparing to dictionary

Tags: python, string, file, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm stuck on a problem and would appreciate any hints/advice. Here is my code so far:

```
name = input("Enter text file name\n")
radio = {'a':'alfa', 'b':'bravo', 'c':'charlie', 'd':'delta','e':'echo', 'f':'foxtrot', 'g':'golf', 'h':'hotel','i':'india', 'j':'juliett', 'k':'kilo', 'l':'lima','m':'mike', 'n':'november', 'o':'oscar', 'p':'papa','q':'quebec', 'r':'romeo', 's':'sierra', 't':'tango','u':'uniform', 'v':'victor', 'w':'whiskey', 'x':'x-ray','y':'yankee', 'z':'zulu'}
def main():

    try:
        f = open(name, "r")
        for line in f.read().split():
            //print(line)
            if line in radio:
                print(radio[line])
            else:
                print("Not an radio/nato alphabet")

        f.close()
    except IOError:
        print("file", nimi, "does not exist.")
main()
```

At the moment my `if line in radio:` can't find single alphabet. I'm wondering is it due to  the fact that "line" is `str` format and radio is a`dict`?

To clarify situation. Here is text file and wanted output.

textfile:

```
A O U
G 1 Y
C A !
```

wanted output:

```
alfa
oscar
uniform

golf
Not an radio/nato alphabet
yankee

charlie
alfa
Not an radio/nato alphabet
```

This is school assignment, and the inspection software isn't the best one. The wanted output has those extra spaces, but when I do for-loop with split() command it doesn't add those new lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the reason is because the letters in the text file are all uppercase, but are set to all lowercase in your dict. One easy way to fix this is to convert the contents of the file to lowercase first:

```
for letter in f.read().lower().split():
    if letter in radio:
        print(radio[letter])
    else:
        print("Not an radio/nato alphabet")
```

In order to add newlines in between each line of text, you could do something like this:

```
for line in f:
    for letter in line.lower().split():
        if letter in radio:
            print(radio[letter])
        else:
            print("Not an radio/nato alphabet")

    print('')
```

Now, you're first iterating over each line. For each line, you're attempting to translate the letter to the NATO code then adding a blank line to separate it from the next line.

Comment: Might want to point out that `print(radio.get(letter, 'Not a radio/nato alphabet'))` is available...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - OP wanted a newline in between each line of text. There was also a typo on my part -- it should have been `for letter in line.lower().split()`

Comment: Thank you very much, the first problem feels very silly now, I don't want to tell how long I didn't get that they were upper cases...

And huge thanks on second problem, would have had troubles to find solution without you!

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `A` to `a` you need to use `lower` to make  it lowercase.

```
if line.lower() in radio:
    print(radio[line.lower()])
```

You can use `dict.get` with a default value for keys that don't exist .

```
def main():
    try:
        f = open(nimi, "r")
        lines = [x.split() for x in f]
        for line in lines:
            for char in line:
                print(radio.get(char.lower(),"Not an radio/nato alphabet"))
            print('')
        f.close()
    except IOError:
        print("file", nimi, "does not exist.")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. The first has been mentioned by the other questions: The characters in the file are uppercase, while your dictionary contains lower-case characters, so use `.lower()` to translate what you read.

The other problem is the "extra space" you mention. The output contains newlines between groups that are lines in the original file. Your code uses `f.read().split()`, which loses the newlines in the original file.

You can iterate through lines of a file using `for line in f:` and then iterate through the characters within a line using `for letter in line.split():`.